# How to remote everything ( KVM like switch eg. VGA, usb Mouse and usb keyboard) over network / wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, web, usb, keyboard-video-mouse

Does anyone know how i can forward mouse, keyboard and vga data over the web? So i can remotely control pc's like on a KVM switch?

The only thing is, a KVM switch requires you to have a physical presence there. Whereas my intention is only to setup the requirements ( add mouse, keyboard and vga to a kvm switch). Then the KVM switch is connected to the web and i can control both the pc's through a web interface ( or something similar).

Comment: I don't understand the question. A KVM over IP only requires your physical presence to get everything connected and configured. Once that's done you access it over the network, no physical presence required. Do you need access to the BIOS and POST phase or just to the OS once it's loaded? If the latter then why not use TeamViewer, GoToAssist, LogMeIn, DameWare, etc., etc.?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question. You were referring to a "standard" KVM. What you need is an IP KVM or an IP module for a standard KVM.

Answer (score 2):

In business environments using appropriate hardware, this is quite common and referred to as [out-of-band management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management). Most big vendors like HP, Dell, Supermicro, etc. implement the [Intelligent Platform Management Interface aka IPMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface), which

> is a set of computer interface specifications for an autonomous computer subsystem that provides management and monitoring capabilities independently of the host system's CPU, firmware (BIOS or UEFI) and operating system. IPMI defines a set of interfaces used by system administrators for out-of-band management of computer systems and monitoring of their operation. For example, IPMI provides a way to manage a computer that may be powered off or otherwise unresponsive by using a network connection to the hardware rather than to an operating system or login shell.

If you're going to implement this in your environment, I would highly encourage you to **not** make the IPMI interface(s) publicly reachable. Quite often new vulnerabilities in the protocol are being identified; the vendors normally take / need some time, to fix these, if at all. Here are some links about these issues from the [US-Cert](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA13-207A), [an article by ITWORLD](http://www.itworld.com/article/2708437/security/ipmi--the-most-dangerous-protocol-you-ve-never-heard-of.html) and [an article of Rapid 7](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2013/07/02/a-penetration-testers-guide-to-ipmi). Make sure you've got access control in place to this / these interface(s), for example via a VPN.